# SQL order by statement

Tags: sql

I want to order some student details according to their distance to school. But within (80-90)km order first. remaining students will be displayed then.
 (select student_name, distance from Students ...........)
ex :

- kamal  ,           88.2 km
- Nimal  ,           86.1 km
- Geetha  ,          82.5 km
- Perera  ,          92.3 km
- Rani   ,           23.1 km
- Shashi    ,        102.4 km

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: Provide DBMS and desired output.

Comment: I don't understand your special condition that first all within 80-90km and then remaining students. Does that mean that students which are 70km away should come after those which are 80km away? However, store only the integer(or decimal) value but not including the `km`.

Comment: You may need to select a list of (80-90) and a list not (80-90), order them separately, and finally union two lists.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: Data type for distance column?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the 80-90 km distances first, use a CASE construct:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN distance BETWEEN 80 AND 90 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  distance;
```

This will get you this order:

```
Geetha    82.5 km
Nimal     86.1 km
kamal     88.2 km
Rani      23.1 km
Perera    92.3 km
Shashi   102.4 km
```

First 80-90 km beginning with 82.5 ending with 88.2, then the other distances beginning with 23.1 ending with 102.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ..., ROUND(distance / 10, 0) AS lakhm, ...
...
ORDER by lakhm
```

This assumes that your SQL version has a ROUND working on expressions. The formal standard requires a column name only I believe. I doubt it works, but `ROUND(distance, -1)` should have an equivalent effect.